# Why when I print a variable outside a for loop it adds 1 to it?

Tags: objective-c, for-loop

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]){

    @autoreleasepool {
        int x = 1;
        for (x = 1; x <= 10; x++)  {
            NSLog(@"%i",x); //the answer here is 10.
        }

        NSLog(@"Number %i",x); //the answer here is 11.
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So my question is, why when I print 'x' outside the for loop it adds 1 to the initial 10?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loop ends once x is greater than 10. Therefore, it goes through the loop 10 times, adds one, which is 11 and breaks out of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

It's not, the loop declaration adds it.

```
for (x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
    // some code
}
```

is like

```
x = 1;
while(x <= 10) {
    // some code
x++;
}
```

When x = 11, the loop stops.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is equal to

```
x = 1;
while(x <= 10)
{
    // log x
    x++;
}
```

As you can see, on the last iteration (x = 10) x is incremented and only then the loop breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Because "for" loop first increments the value of variable x and then compares with the condition!

Answer (score 0):

It because step clause `x++` is run after the last successful loop iteration.  That's how it knows to stop.

1. `x = 1`, then we loop 10 times, incrementing it each time.
2. You get to `x = 10` and your loop body runs its last time.
3. The step clause then runs `x++` and now `x = 11`
4. Check loop condition `x <= 10`, which is now false and the loop exits.

If `x` never got to 11, you would never know when to exit this loop.

Answer (score 0):

The loop iterates for 10 times from 1 to 10 and when the loops ends the value of x becomes 11.